# Python Tkinter: If-statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement, button, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

```
from tkinter import *

def callbackX(button, win, buttonNR):

    print("Pressed button", buttonNR)
    player1.append(buttonNR)
    win.destroy()
    gameScreen()

def gameScreen():

    win = Tk()
    #f = Frame(win)
    if '1' in player1 == 'True':
        b1 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b1, win, '1'))
        b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    if '2' in player1 == 'True':
        b2 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b2, win, '2'))
        b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    if '3' in player1 == 'True':
        b3 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b3, win, '3'))
        b3.grid(row=0, column=2)
    if '4' in player1 == 'True':
        b4 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b4, win, '4'))
        b4.grid(row=1, column=0)
    if '5' in player1 == 'True':
        b5 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b5, win, '5'))
        b5.grid(row=1, column=1)
    if '6' in player1 == 'True':
        b6 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b6, win, '6'))
        b6.grid(row=1, column=2)
    if '7' in player1 == 'True':
        b7 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b7, win, '7'))
        b7.grid(row=2, column=0)
    if '8' in player1 == 'True':
        b8 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b8, win, '8'))
        b8.grid(row=2, column=1)
    if '9' in player1 == 'True':
        b9 = Button(win, text="X", command=lambda: callbackX(b9, win, '9'))
        b9.grid(row=2, column=2)


player1 = []; player2 = []

gameScreen()
```

The program doesn't seem to recognize the if-statement criterion being met. Is this some sort of Tkinter quirk? How can this be fixed?

The code should open a tic-tac-toe game screen, for player1, which closes and reopens the window, without the button that was previously pressed.

Comment: Please describe what `if '1' in player1 == 'True'` will supposed to do

Comment: When a button is pressed the number of the button (buttonNR) will be added to the player1 array. The goal is after the window is destroyed and reopened it will display the game screen again, without the button that was previously pressed.

Answer (score 1):

'True' is a string, just remove the quotes, as True is a bool.

Actually, just simply use

if '1' in player1:

is OK in your case.

Comment: The quotes were something I tryed out of pure desparation. Yet even after the removal of 'True' (and of course the two equals signs) it still displays an empty window. Could it be a bug or is there maybe a built-in function I could use to fix the problem? (Thank you for answering)